# Problem with *.shutdown* command on discord.py

Tags: discord.py, bots

I am currently looking to fix this code. I am trying to make a .shutdown command, which basically logs out of the bot and takes the bot down. I have made a code, but it seems like it is not working. Here is my code. Help is very appreciated ;p

```py
@client.command()
async def shutdown(ctx, *, reason):
    if ctx.message.author.id(581457749724889102):
        ctx.send('Bot is shutting down... ;(')
        logs_channel = client.get_channel(825005282535014420)
        logs_channel.send(f"Bot is being shutdown for: {reason}")
        exit()
    else:
        ctx.send("I'm sorry, only officer grr#6609 can do that."
```

Thanks early for the help!

edit:

here is my error

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\discord bot folder\Nuova cartella\connor.py", line 173, in shutdown
    if ctx.message.author.id(581457749724889102):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\discord bot folder\Nuova cartella\connor.py", line 82, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always consider to `await` your functions. You also have some formation and comprehension errors in the code, maybe take another look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

You can check whether the user executing the command is the owner of the bot. If he is not, there is of course an error message.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner() # Checks if the bot owner exectued the command
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Logging out.")
    await client.logout() # Logging out


@shutdown.error
async def shutdown_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        await ctx.send("You are not the owner of the bot.") # Error message
```

**What did we do?**

- `await`ed most of the functions.
- Built in a check to check if the owner executed the command.
- Built in an error handler which will give out a message if a non-owner tries to shutdown the bot.